# Fix: Laravel Git Clone in AWS Btnami LAMP Stack Error

Tags: laravel, amazon-ec2, lamp, bitnami

I git cloned a laravel site into a bitnami LAMP stack and it is producing this error.

```
UnexpectedValueException
The stream or file "/opt/bitnami/projects/mel/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run this command `sudo chmod -R 777 storage` in your project directory

Comment: Thanks @mmabdelgawad I solved it by reuploading the files, they actually got deleted while I was deploying from local to live.